# snmptrapd can't forward the received traps to a different port on the same host

Tags: forward, snmptrapd

I am currently attempting to configure snmptrapd to do trap forwarding.With my current configuration, snmptrapd is receiving and logging
incoming traps, but it it does not appear to be forwarding them.
The contents of my snmptrapd.conf file are as follows:

```
disableAuthorization yes
traphandle default  /usr/sbin/snmptthandler
authCommunity log public
forward default 127.0.0.1:1062
```

When I run snmptrapd as follows:

```
snmptrapd -f -Le -d
```

I can see traps being received as follow result,

```
Received 67 byte packet from UDP: [191.50.2.21]49801->[191.50.3.75]:162
0000: 30 41 02 01  00 04 08 54  4E 50 49 47  50 29 2A A4    0A.....USPIGP)*.
0016: 32 06 08 2B  06 01 06 03  01 01 05 40  04 C0 A8 06    2..+.......@....
0032: 0C 02 01 04  02 01 00 43  04 3D F3 FC  72 30 14 30    .......C.=..r0.0
0048: 12 06 0A 2B  06 01 04 01  09 02 01 05  00 40 04 B9    ...+.........@..
0064: 5E 6F 01
```

When I send a test trap from localhost,

```
Sending 96 bytes to UDP: [127.0.0.1]:1062->[0.0.0.0]:0
0000: 30 5E 02 01  00 04 06 70  75 62 6C 69  63 A4 51 06    0^.....public.Q.
0016: 09 2B 06 01  06 03 01 01  05 05 40 04  7F 00 00 01    .+........@.....
0032: 02 01 06 02  01 11 43 04  02 12 FA 93  30 32 30 30    ......C.....0200
0048: 06 09 2B 06  01 06 03 01  01 05 05 04  23 4A 75 73    ..+.........#Jus
0064: 74 20 61 20  74 65 73 74  2E 2E 2E 62  6C 61 62 6C    t a test...blabl
0080: 61 62 6C 61  62 6C 2E 2E  2E 2E 2E 2E  2E 2E 2E 2E    ablabl..........
```

I would appreciate any assistance with further debugging and
ultimately addressing this issue.

Thank you.

Andrew

Answer (score 2):

If you want to forward the trap you need to enable the net type:

```
    authCommunity log,net public
```